# Show posts from custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

- Update 2
  Adding name as field instead of the slug and adding the_title() just give me an echo of the page title...

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'feestlocaties',
        'showposts' => '3',
        'orderby'   => 'rand',  
         'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'locatie',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => the_title(),
                ),
            ),
        );
```

- Update Jonnhyd23's code worked like a charm!! Thanks!
  Is there a way you can make the terms dynamic? Like the title is Amsterdam can I do something like `'terms' => '<?php the_title(); ?>'` or something like that?

I've been going at this for the last couple of hours. Maybe someone here can help me?

I want to show specif posts from a custom taxonomy in a loop.
This is the situation:

- custom taxonomy: feestlocaties
- And the the posts i want to show have Amsterdam selected (checked) (like categories).

Code i tried:

```
<div id="main-filter">

    <!-- Start the Loop. -->
    <?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'feestlocaties',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'locatie',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'amsterdam',
        ),
    ),
); ?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>


        <!-- Test if the current post is in category 3. -->
        <!-- If it is, the div box is given the CSS class "post-cat-three". -->
        <!-- Otherwise, the div box is given the CSS class "post". -->
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <div class="container post-item">
                <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(400,355)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 no-padding">
                <h1 class="overzicht"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); ?>

                <div class="col-sm-12 no-padding loop-overzicht">
                    <?php $prijs = get_Field('vanaf_prijs'); ?>
                    <?php $pers = get_Field('aantal_personen'); ?>
                    <?php $time = get_Field('tijdsduur'); ?>
                <ul class="loop-opsomming text-right">
                    <li><?php echo '<i class="fa fa-euro"></i>Vanaf ' . $prijs . ' p.p.' ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo '<i class="fa fa-group"></i>Vanaf ' . $pers . ' personen' ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Vanaf ' . $time . ' uur' ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </a>
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

But nothing is showing. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just showing the arguments you're using for WP_Query, or is this all of your code? Try using the tax_query parameter.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'feestlocaties',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'amsterdam',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();


//execute code


endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Hi Johnnyd23,
Please see my full code in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, 'your_post_type' is probably not your post type.

Comment: I know! I was to fast. Your code works like a charm! Thanks. Is it possible you could look at my update?

Comment: That could work if the title of the page you were on was 'Amsterdam'. You would also need to update the 'field' parameter in the tax_query to 'name' instead of 'slug'

Comment: And then just add '<?php the_title(); ?>' as the terms... ill have a go at it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that didnt work. I just echo's the name of the page.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fiddeld around abit and this is the code that works for me. Cheers Johnnyd23

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'feestlocaties',
    'showposts' => '3',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',  
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'locatie',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => get_the_title(),
        ),
    ),
); ?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
```

This will make the title the post dynamicly in the WP_Query.